# Firestore array-contains-any is not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

```
"@angular/fire": "5.2.3", 
"firebase": "7.4.0",
```

Note: `members` is an `array` and 0,1,2 is `map` data structures.

[image]

*service.ts*

```
 getUserChatGroups(uid: string): Observable<DocumentChangeAction<MessageGroupMemberModel>[]> {
    return this.afs.collection<MessageGroupMemberModel>(`messageGroups`, ref => ref.where('members', 'array-contains-any', [uid])).snapshotChanges();
  }
```

*page.ts*

```
 init(): void {
    const uid: string = this.authService.getUserUid();
    this.chatService.getUserChatGroups(uid).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('request completed')
    );

  }
```

No errors. But it doesn't return any value. But it has values. Is there something wrong with my query?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `array-contains-any` (and also the `array-contains`) operator check whether the array contains an element that exactly-and-completely matches the information that you pass into the call. So in your case, you need to pass in both the `id` and the `joinDateTime` in order to match.

```
ref.where('members', 'array-contains-any', [{ id: uid, joinedDateTime: ... }])
```

If you don't know the `joinedDateTime` for the user, you can't query the array in your current data structure. The normal solution is to store a separate array field `memberIds` in the document too, which contains just the UIDs of the members. Then you can find the members by querying on *that* field:

```
ref.where('members', 'array-contains', [uid])
```

Or

```
ref.where('members', 'array-contains-any', [uid, uid2, uid3])
```

Comment: Is it suitable for big arrays? If it's not, Do you have any suggestions?

In the documentation, it says up to 10 equality https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any

Comment: not-in supports up to 10 comparison values.
The sum of filters, sort orders, and parent document path (1 for a subcollection, 0 for a root collection) in a query cannot exceed 100. This is calculated based on the disjunctive normal form of the query.