# Firebase Query Array Angular Using "in"

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am facing a problem right now. I really don't understand where is my fault.

I try to query with library [@angular/fire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire)

Following is my query code:

```js
return this.firestore.collection('Transaksi', ref => ref
  .where('travel', '==', travel)
  .where('waktu', 'in', [1, 5]) //this line is problem.
  .where('tanggal', '==', tanggal)
  .where('dariKota', '==', dari)
  .where('menujuKota', '==', menuju))
  .valueChanges()
```

But, I only get value where when `waktu == 5`.

If I use

```js
return this.firestore.collection('Transaksi', ref => ref
  .where('travel', '==', travel)
  .where('waktu', '==', 1)
  .where('tanggal', '==', tanggal)
  .where('dariKota', '==', dari)
  .where('menujuKota', '==', menuju))
  .valueChanges()
```

I get the correct value when I use `waktu == 1` or `waktu == 5` (normal).
But didn't get anything when I use `waktu in [1, 5]`.
I try to use `waktu in [5, 1]` but got the result.

Is something there I am  missing?
or in angular, `in` still not supportted?

Comment: As per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) the operator should work. Have you checked if you are using the latest Releases of the Libraries: [Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node), [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/releases)? Additionally, is your query call exactly matching the data bound to "waktu"? I am asking this question, after stumbling across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052349/firestore-array-contains-any-is-not-working-properly) example.

Comment: @ArtemisGeorgakopoulou yes, i use latest release Node.js dan angular, use anguler fire latest too. yes, my value of `waktu` is number, so it would be no problem. as i write in my question, if i use `waktu == 5` the result came out. but not came out when `waktu in [5, 1]`.

Comment: Could you please try with the following code: where('waktu', 'array-contains-any',
    [5,1]) and let me if it works or not.